# combining different tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 3 tables which i want to combine in a empty table,

```
Table A contains:
a_id | name
1  |  john
2  |  mic
3  |  rog
```

and

```
Table B contains:
    b_id | name
    10  |  rims
    11  |  sara
```

and

```
Table c contains:
        c_id | name
        20  |  johny
        21  |  sun
        22  |  rose
        23  |  pash
        24  |  ed
        25  |  ese
```

and i have one empty table D, which will have id's of all three above tables:
Table D columns are;

```
a_id  | b_id | c_id
```

how can i insert all id's in table D? and 
when i run query.

```
Select*from table_D
```

it should show all id's from table(a,b,c).

Comment: and your past questions have been solved? none have been marked as such. I take it you don't know how, right?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner can i mark as solved even if it didn't work for me?

Comment: No. I noticed one that you did say it worked so you can mark that off :-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ok thank you, it executed but didn't work as i expected.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner can you please assist me in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, because you don't specify what `d` looks like.  Let me assume that you was a Cartesian product of all `id`s.  This seems like a reasonable assumption.  Then:

```
insert into d (a_id, b_id, c_id)
    select a.a_id, b.b_id, c.c_id
    from a cross join b cross join c;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/BARE75075) is a rextester demonstrating it.

Comment: Thank you, this command executed, but table D is still empty, can you please tell me why?

Comment: @iMatt . . . That would happen if any of the tables being combined were empty.

Comment: all tables have data. some number of rows may vary. table d is empty because i want to insert id's from all three tables in it.

Comment: this is how i am writing your query:
 <?php

 include_once 'dbh.php';
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iscptt</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$sql = "insert timetable (teacher_id, class_id, subject_id)
    select teachers.teacher_id, class.class_id, subjects.subject_id
    from teachers cross join subjects cross join class";
 
 

?>
</body>

Comment: @iMatt . . . It works when I run it.  I added a Rextester example.

Comment: THANK YOU, i will look into issue, thank you for answer. i hope to see you in future too.

Comment: is it necessary to use union all when i create tables? only then your query will work?

Comment: @iMatt . . . That is how I created the tables to illustrate that the code works.  I presume that you already have the tables.

Comment: i was able to combine all tables, but when first table values are inserted, after that second table values are inserted and then third tables value. leaving all above columns null.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you ask for:

```
INSERT d
SELECT a.id, b.id, c.id
FROM a CROSS JOIN b CROSS JOIN c
```

Though I doubt it's what you want!